# Swift need to reload TableView that is contained within a containerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a tableViewController with in a containerView in the main view of my app. The user can elect one of three buttons which needs to pass a new value to the tableViewController and reload the tableView.

I can't seem to find an example of how best to do this programmatically.

Any suggestions or links to examples thanks.

Adding some code of what I have tried

```
@IBAction func checkins10(sender: AnyObject) {
    statusImage10.hidden = false
    statusImage1.hidden = true
    statusImage5.hidden = true
    self.hourWindow = 10.00

    reloadCheckInView()
}


func reloadCheckInView() {
    let checkInsTableViewController: FriendCheckInTableViewController = FriendCheckInTableViewController(nibName: "FriendCheckInTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    checkInsTableViewController.checkInsTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Updated

```
func reloadCheckInView() {
   // let checkInsTableViewController: FriendCheckInTableViewController = FriendCheckInTableViewController(nibName: "FriendCheckInTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    var viewControllerStoryboardId = "FriendCheckInTableViewController"
    var storyboardName = "Main"
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let checkInsTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerStoryboardId) as UIViewController!
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what doesn't work? Need to be more specific, and it helps if you can post some code.

Comment: I just added what I just tried but I am getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `checkInsTableViewController.checkInsTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: then your checkInsTableViewController isn't getting initialised correctly.

Comment: Would using NSNotifications be a better choice? If I publish a notification from the MainView would the containerView subscribing act?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a new instance of FriendCheckInTableViewController by loading it from a bundle. You need to have a reference to the one in the storyboard in your containing view and set up the connection when editing the storyboard.

Comment: I think I am heading down that road. I changed my code in `reloadCheckInView` to `var viewControllerStoryboardId = "FriendCheckInTableViewController"`
        `var storyboardName = "Main"`
        `var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())`
        `let checkInsTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerStoryboardId) as UIViewController!`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a var for the tableview and connect it in your storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkInsTableView: UITableView?
```

Connect it to your tableview in the storyboard and just refresh data as needed.

```
self.checkInsTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: If the var `checkInsTableView` is connected to my tableViewController which is in a containerView of my main view. How would I get the `self.checkInsTableView.reloadData()` to be called?

Comment: Are you trying to refresh a table view in another view controller that isn't visible? You should be calling .reloadData() in the current view on your current table view. If you need to refresh data somewhere else then you should restructure your question to get a better answer.

Comment: Or give more code for your current class so you can get more help as more context will help everyone figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Since I don't think I'm going to do much more than just show the table I went ahead and just used a UITableView vs a containerView and that presented no issues